# JMeter - difference between response times of Parallel controller and HTTP Sampler

Tags: jmeter

There is substantial difference between response times of Parallel controller ( with requests for all resources, and 6 connections) and HTTP Sampler of main request( with "download embedded resources" checked, with 6 connection). Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing different response times it means that you either not sending the same requests or sending them in a different way. The best way to check is using a [network sniffer](https://www.dnsstuff.com/packet-sniffers) tool to compare the network footprint of both approaches.

1. HTTP Request sampler duration is calculated as:

   - main request
   - plus the largest response time of 1st chunk of 6 resources
   - plus the largest response time of 2nd chunk of 6 resources
   - etc.
2. Parallel Controller acts the same but it doesn't add the main request duration to the overall response time

Also if you have more than one/request and/or iteration and [HTTP Cache Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cache-manager/) added to the test plan

In general you should not be comparing HTTP Request's response with a plugin, you should compare it with the real browser